Firefox add-on reviewed failed and offer a build report
I am using Plasmo and React developing a browser extendsion. When I submitted the extendsion to firefox, I got a info as below


Sources, specifically Build not reproducing: Reproducing the submitted release version based on the provided source code package and instructions failed. You can access the console output at https://prod.pastebin.prod.webservices.mozgcp.net/yj1sOucs . Environment used for building: Node 18.20.2, npm 10.5.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 Please test your build in a clean environment to make sure it is reproducible. If necessary, update the source code package and/or the instructions to reproduce.Please read through the instructions at https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/publish/source-code-submission/ .


I have accessed the url(https://prod.pastebin.prod.webservices.mozgcp.net/yj1sOucs), it looks like a build error. This version(0.0.13) has publish on chrome and edge. So I think there is nothing problem in source code. Can anyone know how to fix this build error?
The package.json as below
{
  "name": "weread-web-extension",
  "displayName": "微信读书助手 - 前夕",
  "version": "0.0.13",
  "description": "自动阅读、自定义菜单、任意屏占比, 全方位打造沉浸式阅读体验",
  "author": "前夕",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run start:chrome",
    "start:firefox": "plasmo dev --target=firefox-mv2",
    "start:chrome": "plasmo dev --target=chrome-mv3",
    "build:firefox": "npx plasmo build --target=firefox-mv2",
    "build:chrome": "npx plasmo build --target=chrome-mv3",
    "build:edge": "npx plasmo build --target=edge-mv3",
    "build:all": "npm run build:firefox && npm run build:chrome && npm run build:edge"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@plasmohq/messaging": "0.5.0",
    "@plasmohq/storage": "1.8.0",
    "daisyui": "4.9.0",
    "jquery": "3.7.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lottie-web": "^5.12.2",
    "plasmo": "0.85.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-daisyui": "5.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "zustand": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ianvs/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "4.1.1",
    "@types/chrome": "0.0.258",
    "@types/jquery": "3.5.29",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/node": "20.11.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.48",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.18",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.19",
    "postcss": "8.4.38",
    "prettier": "3.2.4",
    "tailwindcss": "3.4.3",
    "typescript": "5.3.3"
  },
  "manifest": {
    "host_permissions": [
      "https://*/*"
    ]
  }
}


